# Gradle - publish artifacts

Tags: gradle, ivy

I want to publish artifacts to ivy repository but it doesn't work. I read [this article](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) and after read created this sample build:

```
task ivyPublishTest << {
    def buildDir = new File("build")
    buildDir.mkdirs()
    def fileToPublish = new File("build/file.abc")
    fileToPublish.write("asdasdasd")
}

artifacts {
    archives(ivyPublishTest.fileToPublish) {
        name 'gradle-test-artifact'
        builtBy ivyPublishTest
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url "http://my.ivy.repo/ivyrep/shared"
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the problem is that it doesn't work. I get this error `Could not find property 'fileToPublish' on task ':ivyPublishTest'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy, `def` creates a local variable, which is lexically scoped. Therefore, `fileToPublish` is not visible outside the task action. Additionally, configuration has to be done in the *configuration phase* (i.e. the declaration and assignment of `fileToPublish` in your task action would come too late). Here is a correct solution:

```
task ivyPublishTest {
    // configuration (always evaluated)
    def buildDir = new File("build")
    ext.fileToPublish = new File("build/file.abc")
    doLast {
        // execution (only evaluated if and when the task executes)
        buildDir.mkdirs()
        fileToPublish.write("asdasdasd")
    }
}

artifacts {
    // configuration (always evaluated)
    archives(ivyPublishTest.fileToPublish) {
        name 'gradle-test-artifact'
        builtBy ivyPublishTest
    }
}
```

`ext.fileToPublish = ...` declares an *extra property*, a new property attached to an existing object that's visible everywhere the object (task in this case) is visible. You can read more about extra properties [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aextra_task_properties) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: Thanks but now gradle shows this error `Could not find method archives() for arguments [build\file.abc, build_343353k3f117pa3tdkoiplr9of$_run_closure2_clos...`

Comment: You probably didn't apply a plugin such as `java` that declares an `archives` configuration. Check out the sample builds in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: OK, I understand now. Can I publish artifact without any plugin?